# Can't unlock keyring in Seahorse (gnome-keyring)

Tags: gnome, login, password, gnome-keyring, seahorse

I wanted to change my master password for gnome-keyring (login), but I can't unlock it (as advised) in `seahorse` (I'm on 16.04, GDM, seahorse version: 3.20.0, and gnome-keyring-daemon version is: 3.18.3):

[image]

What is wrong here?